# OpenVPN won't assign static IPs

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, openvpn

I have OpenVPN setup and running correctly. The problem is I want to assign static IPs to certain users on my VPN, so they always get the exact same IP every time.

My setup is for PAM authentication, this is working fine:

```
client-cert-not-required
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so login
```

My username is `joel` and also it is working fine as I can login to the VPN from any PC using this username. Here is my `server.conf` file for IP static config:

```
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
```

CCD Directory and the User file are both owned by `nobody` as my process runs as them:

[image]
[image]

Contents of the user file:

[image]

Even with all of this I still do not have a static IP when I connect as user `joel`. I get different IPs everytime, from `.6` to `.10`, but never `.4`.

Comment: What are you using for your topology?  Is this tun or tap?  Do you have old Windows clients connecting to this system?  Does your config have `username-as-common-name` set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using username/password authentication disables any Common Name use by OpenVPN. So it doesn't set the client Common name when logging in.

The solution is to set the following flag in the `server.conf` file and restart the OpenVPN server:

```
username-as-common-name
```

This tells OpenVPN to set the username to the client's Common Name when connecting. Since the file is named after Common Name this is required or OpenVPN doesn't know which file to check.

Answer (score 2):

First, do you have a `client-connect` script in place?  If so, any IP directives from that take precedence.

Secondly, according to the OpenVPN documentation, the `client-config-dir` only uses the client's X.509 common name to determine which file to use.  You can validate if the `joel` file is not matching by creating a DEFAULT file.  It appears that you are not using client certificates at all, which may preclude the use of the `client-config-dir` option.

Comment: Thanks for that! It was just what I needed, I didn't know that I had to tell OpenVPN to set the Common Name to username, I thought it already did. Using `username-as-common-name` on server side did it.